# Converting Pd Data frame to a 2 mode/Bipartite networkx graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, networkx, bipartite

hope you are healthy!

I'm trying to convert the follow data matrix, which shows what sharing apps people are using, into a bipartite network graph - where there are two types of nodes, the users and the Apps.

Additionally, I would like to have weighted edges to indicate frequency of use, and values indicating the number of new connections made with each app, but for now, any help just with the simple graph connecting edges and nodes would be great!

The current data frame -

```
df.head(10)
Out[20]: 
  Unnamed: 0  Airbnb  Peerby  ...  Marktplaats  Together  Snappcar
0      James       1       1  ...            0         1         0
1     Andrew       1       0  ...            0         0         1
2      Sarah       1       0  ...            0         1         0
3       Nick       0       1  ...            1         0         1
4       Mary       0       0  ...            0         0         0
5      Julia       1       1  ...            1         0         1
6      Steve       0       0  ...            0         1         1
7       Mike       1       0  ...            1         0         1 

[8 rows x 9 columns]
```

Right now I'm going off this, but not sure how to fill in the appropriate source and target or how that works with  a graph with two types of nodes --

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd


#Importing data

df = pd.read_csv("P2P Trial 1.csv")



edges = pd.DataFrame({'source' : [],
                      'target' : [],
                      'weight' : []})

nodes = pd.DataFrame({'node' : [''],
                      'name' : [''],
                      'Apps' : ['']})

G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(edges, 'source', 'target', 'weight')
```

I know I'm a long way off but just trying to get learn and get things going.

Any assistance, or points the right direction are much appreciated! :)

Links to learning resources are also appreciated :) !

Comment: Just for clarification a two mode network is a bipartite graph?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Perhaps I should use that term instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following DataFrame (a sample of yours, note that the first column is Unnamed):

```
  Unnamed  Airbnb  Peerby  Marktplaats  Together  Snappcar
0   James       1       1            0         1         0
1  Andrew       1       0            0         0         1
2   Sarah       1       0            0         1         0
3    Nick       0       1            1         0         1
4    Mary       0       0            0         0         0
5   Julia       1       1            1         0         1
6   Steve       0       0            0         1         1
7    Mike       1       0            1         0         1
```

You could do the following:

```
# the trick is to use melt to transform the graph into (source, target) format
result = df.melt(id_vars='Unnamed')

# only select columns with 1
filtered = result[result['value'] == 1].rename(columns={'Unnamed': 'source', 'variable': 'target'})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(filtered)

for edge in G.edges:
    print(edge)
```

**Output**

```
('James', 'Airbnb')
('James', 'Peerby')
('James', 'Together')
('Airbnb', 'Andrew')
('Airbnb', 'Sarah')
('Airbnb', 'Julia')
('Airbnb', 'Mike')
('Andrew', 'Snappcar')
('Sarah', 'Together')
('Julia', 'Peerby')
('Julia', 'Marktplaats')
('Julia', 'Snappcar')
('Mike', 'Marktplaats')
('Mike', 'Snappcar')
('Peerby', 'Nick')
('Nick', 'Marktplaats')
('Nick', 'Snappcar')
('Together', 'Steve')
('Steve', 'Snappcar')
```